# How to create .cab File from Multiple CSV file with Backup and Log FIle

Tags: batch-file, makecab

Currently we are creating .cab file from multiple CSV File that exist in the folder, however the script below won't work.

This is make cab, backup, create log and delete source file.

Script below is creating cab file but cannot open the cab file with error message "Cannot open the cabinet file.

MAKE_CAB.BAT

```
 @echo off  
SET RETURN=0
SET DATE=%DATE: =%
SET DATE=%DATE:/=%
SET CURRENTDATE=%date:~7,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~5,2%
SET DIR_PATH=G:\WMS\HBN\BB\IF\OUTBOUND\ZR23019B\
SET SOURCE=G:\WMS\SEND\ZR23019B\*.CSV
SET BACKUP=%DIR_PATH%\BACKUP\

::------------------------s-
SET time_tmp=%time: =0%
SET hh=%time_tmp:~0,2%
SET mi=%time_tmp:~3,2%
SET ss=%time_tmp:~6,2%
SET sss=%time_tmp:~9,2%
::-------------------------

SET DATE_TIME=%CURRENTDATE%%hh%%mi%%ss%
SET LOGNAME=%DIR_PATH%LOG\LOG_MAKE_CAB_%DATE_TIME%.txt

SET DDF_FILE=G:\WMS\BIN\SEND\ZR23019B\MAKE_CAB.ddf


echo .Set CabinetNameTemplate=BA10003F.cab > %DDF_FILE%
echo .Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=%DIR_PATH% >> %DDF_FILE%

dir %SOURCE% /b >> %DDF_FILE%
cd /d %SOURCE%

copy /y %SOURCE%*.* %BACKUP% >> %LOGNAME%
makecab /f %DDF_FILE% >> BA10003F
if errorlevel 1 goto ERROR
if errorlevel 0 goto DELETE

:ERROR
SET RETURN=1
exit /b %RETURN%

:DELETE
del /q %SOURCE%* >> %LOGNAME%
exit /b %RETURN%
```

MAKE_CAB.DDF

```
.Set CabinetNameTemplate=BA10003F.cab 
.Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=G:\WMS\HBN\BB\IF\OUTBOUND\ZR23019B\
```

Thank you

it will create .cab file from multiple CSV file create backup file and log file and delete the csv file from source.

Comment: Please change lines five and six, so that you are not redefining the built-in variable already named `DATE`. Better yet, just remove those lines and change line seven to use `%date:~-4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%` instead.

Comment: hi @compo sorry what do you mean by change this line?
SET DATE=%DATE: =%
SET DATE=%DATE:/=%

Comment: ``` @echo off  ``` is line one!

Comment: Got is sir @compo, however the still cannot access the create .cab File.

Comment: You should also [Edit] your question to explain to us exactly how you are running your batch file and show us the command line and argumets you are passing to it. This allows everyone to at least have a better chance of reproducing your reported problem.

Comment: hi sir @compo, yes sir as indicated above the command line for both .Bat file and . DDF file is included above, also the main objective is that after manually running the .bat file it create's .Cab file but error encounter when opening the .cab file "Cannot open the cabinet file." when trying to unzip error can not open the file as [CAB] archive is not archive.

Comment: Your script indicates that you are running the script using a method which passes at least two arguments along with it. We need to see that as it relies on those two arguments. You should also note that your 'DiskDirectoryTemplate' seems to be a directory named `<space>` within `G:\WMS\HBN\BB\IF\OUTBOUND\ZR23019B`.

Comment: basically Objective is to Make Cab, Backup file , Create log and delete source,

other arguments might not be necessary.

need to remove this maybe, assuming file will just be locally saved in some folders.
SET PRG_ID=%1
SET FILE_ID=%2

Comment: I've never used `makecab`. I note that the `MAKE_CAB.DDF` file has a trailing space on each line because of (eg) `...3F.cab > %DD...` . Remove the space before the redirector to eliminate that trailing space.

Comment: hi sir @magoo thank you for your reply, do you know other method on compressing csv file to .cab file using Scripts?

Comment: [How to use MakeCab](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1977#p8651)